# Programmatically change Telerik GridEditCommandColumn EditText per row in RadGrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid with a GridEditCommandColumn.  I'd like to have the EditText property of each row change based on the contents of the row.  Eg, change EditText from 'Edit' to 'Edit Product' or 'Edit Bundle' based on the contents of the row.

I tried using databinding syntax but got an error saying that it doesn't support databinding.

**Is there an event I can hook into to change the value of EditText programmatically per row?**

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? Anyway you can easily find and edit through OnItemDataBound... Put in UniqueName on the Edit Command Column.. Will help you to find the control for it.

.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
        <MasterTableView>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" UniqueName="GridEditCommandColumn"></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("A") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("A");
        string[] array = { "Product", "Goods", "Category", "Foods" };

        // Loop & Add
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(array[i]);

        // Bind
        RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
        RadGrid1.DataBind();

        dt.Dispose();

    }
}

protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    // CHeck
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        // Variable & Find Control
        string value = string.Empty;
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        LinkButton lbtnEdit = item["GridEditCommandColumn"].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
        Label lbl = item.FindControl("lbl") as Label;

        // Check & Set Value
        if (lbl != null) value = lbl.Text.Trim();

        // Check
        if (lbtnEdit != null)
            lbtnEdit.Text = "Edit " + value;
    }
}
```

Result 
[image]